# FCL Error With ComputeSignedDistancePairwisePoints in PyDrake

Tags: drake

I'm getting a somewhat frequent error when performing collision queries using the `ComputeSignedDistancePairwisePoints` function, and it doesn't seem easy to find the conditions which cause the error. I saw [this issue](https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl/issues/398) from 2019 on Github referencing the same error, but there weren't many details for the "fix".

The conditions of my simulation are as follows: I apply VHACD to decompose an object I would like to manipulate into several coarse convex bodies that jointly act as the collision geometry. The fingertips of the robot are modeled as spheres. At a seemingly random point in the simulation, this error occurs. Is there any recourse? Should I do something special with my collision geometries to prevent this from happening?

```
*** RuntimeError: Error with configuration
  Original error message: external/fcl/include/fcl/narrowphase/detail/convexity_based_algorithm/gjk_libccd-inl.h:(1719): validateNearestFeatureOfPolytopeBeingEdge(): The origin is outside of the polytope. This should already have been identified as separating.
  Shape 1: Sphere(0.01200000000000000025)
  X_FS1
 -0.40370167831914760548 -0.019479333109567995019   -0.9146832842595900015   0.74747104350671045303
  -0.4289595844695910376   0.88710005183204809764   0.17043231187557600359  0.025509175267072643767
  0.80809568110093199511   0.46116597188125679763  -0.36647962639802561524  0.045779118115638992026
                       0                        0                        0                        1
  Shape 2: Convex(v count: 16, f count: 28)
  X_FS2
  0.98447767053732548881   0.11941117744570119152  -0.12862615175162719905   0.70727978567772809004
 -0.11946133329759119068   0.99281162514245557826 0.0073530149434261633107  0.019925905554638502493
  0.12857957092852342895 0.0081269725622573462526   0.99166589447091968434  0.044593263795921309067
                       0                        0                        0                        1
  Solver: GjkSolver_libccd
    collision_tolerance:      2.0097183471152322134e-14
    max collision iterations: 500
    distance tolerance:       9.9999999999999995475e-07
    max distance iterations:  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of good news/bad news.

**Good news**: this isn't your fault.

**Bad news**: there's probably nothing you can do about it. It's most likely a bug in FCL.

**Good news**: the error message should provide *almost* enough information to reproduce the error and hunt it down.

**Bad news**: to be enough, we need to know what the convex shape is; we know it has 16 vertices and 28 faces, but that's not enough to reproduce the bug.

**Hypothesis**
It may well turn out there's a "problem" with the convex shape, but we need to get a hold of it to determine that. It's worth noting that [VHACD advertises creating "near" convex parts](https://github.com/kmammou/v-hacd). Neither Drake nor FCL particularly validates whether the shape is *actually* convex or not and it could well be that your shape is falling into that crack, leading to an inconsistent view on the distance problem.

**Conclusion**: This definitely constitutes a bug that should be addressed. I've opened an [issue for it in Drake](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18704). If you can track down the convex shape details and submit them there, we can tackle the problem.

Comment: Random follow up: presumably you're creating the decomposition and then referencing each component in a urdf/sdf file. Have you used the `drake:declare_convex/>` tag? If so, you might try removing it. That'll *force* Drake and FCL to ignore the actual mesh topology and use a convex-hull representation of the components instead. That might make your bug go away.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I'm actually programmatically generating these meshes and saving them to a temp directory as an exported Trimesh, which I then load into Drake by declaring it a `Convex` shape. FWIW, I also just tried using `Mesh` instead and still eventually ran into the same error. I'll see if I can extract the temp file causing the issue to hand over.

EDIT: I'd also like to add that the simulation conditions are random, so it's not just a particular instance of a weird generated geometry causing this, but a whole class of sphere-to-VHACD geometries causing issues.

Comment: I have a set of .obj files representing the geometry of an offending object (not sure which is specifically causing the bug). Is there an email address (or other private method) I can share a download link with?

Comment: How big is the set? You might consider simply tarring them up and then submitting them to the issue linked above. Also, we know the number of vertices the offending mesh has (16). If any of those have 16 vertices, you could just send those along.

Comment: BTW I've updated the issue and need some feedback; I'm looking for more information.